# How to create Account with ID in corda

Tags: corda

I am using accounts library for my project in Corda. I need to create accounts with custom IDs for the account. Till Now I am creating accounts using the CreateAccount Flow which accepts only one parameter which is account name. the Code for the Create Account Flow is as follow:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
public class CreateAccountFlow extends FlowLogic<String> {
    private String accountName;
//    private UUID userID;
    public CreateAccountFlow(String accountName) {
        this.accountName = accountName;

    }

    @Override
    @Suspendable
    public String call() throws FlowException {
        StateAndRef<AccountInfo> newAccount = null;
        try {
//            newAccount = getServiceHub().cordaService(KeyManagementBackedAccountService.class).createAccount(accountName).get();
            newAccount =(StateAndRef<AccountInfo>) subFlow(new CreateAccount(accountName));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        AccountInfo acc = newAccount.getState().getData();
        return "Account "+acc.getName()+ " Created";
    }
}
```

Is there any way so I can create Account with ID and Name both??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own version of the flow which extends `CreateAccount` and has a **public** constructor that accepts both `name` and `identifier`; as you can see [here](https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/master/workflows/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/accounts/workflows/flows/CreateAccount.kt), the flow already has that constructor but it's marked as **private**.

Comment: Thank Adel, But an error is popping up as I am extending the CreateAccount class, The Error is : Cannot inherit from final 'com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.workflows.flows.CreateAccount'